# Why won't my JS modify this html?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a basic Rock, Paper, Scissors Game, and it works so far, but I REALLY want it to take in the userInput for "name" and then greet the user like "welcome, name"

But its not working Below is the code with the parts that aren't working highlighted

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="myJS.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!--right here-->
    <p id = "Name"> Welcome, Name</h1>
<!--ends here-->
    <a href="http://cooltext.com"><img src="http://images.cooltext.com/3974705.png"
     width="1056" height="81" alt="Rock Paper Scissors" /></a>

    <button onclick="RPS()" <a href="#" class="style" >Click Me To Play!</a></button>
    <p><br<br></p>
    <p id="counter">You won 0 times!</p>
</body>
```

And here's the JS

```
var timesWon = 0;
//below = part that won't work//
//check PLEASE
var name = "Person";
name = prompt("What's your name?");
document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML = "Welcome, "+name + "!";
document.write(name);
//END OF UNWORKING PART
var counter = 0;
function RPS()
{
     var userChoice = prompt("So, "+ name + ", rock, paper, or scissors?        (All LowerCase Please!)");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
var opposition = "";

if(computerChoice > 0.67)
{
    opposition  = "rock";

    if(userChoice == ("rock"))
    {
        alert("you tied!");
    }
    else if(userChoice == "paper")
    {
        alert("you won!");
        counter++;
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "You won "+counter + " times";
    }
    else if(userChoice ==("scissors"))
    {
        alert("you lost!");
    }
}
else if(computerChoice > 0.34)
{
    opposition  = "paper";

    if(userChoice == ("rock"))
    {
        alert("you won!");
        counter++;
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "You won "+counter + " times";

    }
    else if(userChoice == "paper")
    {
        alert("you tied!");
    }
    else if(userChoice ==("scissors"))
    {
        alert("you lost!");
    }
}
else
{
    opposition  = "scissors";

    if(userChoice == ("rock"))
    {
        alert("you lost!");
    }
    else if(userChoice == "paper")
    {
        alert("you won!");
        counter++;
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "You won "+counter + " times";

    }
    else if(userChoice ==("scissors"))
    {
        alert("you tied!");
    }
    else 
    {
        alert("Invalid Input");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Has your HTML actually loaded by that point? Is your script included at the top of your document or at the bottom?

Comment: `document.write` is wiping the page. Don't use it. [Here you can see it working](http://jsfiddle.net/cgyj4egm/).

Comment: Document write will be clearing the whole document. Why is it after `document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML = "Welcome, "+name + "!";`?

Comment: looks like your js is running before the page has loaded, so your document.getElementById is returning undefined. Move the `<script src="myJS.js"></script>` to the bottom of the doc

Comment: also you could do `computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);` to generate 0/1/2 to tidy things up a bit

Comment: Your html structure is not correct as well...<p id="name"> tag is not ending. Also the html is having error in button tag. all browser will not work with malformed html. Please correct those.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I implemented all the advice you gave me.

Comment: Also, whats a good IDE for JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the prompt running as soon as the game starts. Put that in it's own function:

```
function getUserName(){
    window.name = prompt("What's your name?");
    document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML = "Welcome, "+name + "!";
}
```

And then call that function on the body load:

```
<body onload="getUserName();">
```

Also, you have to close the name element with the corresponding tag. You have `</h1>` instead of `</p>`, and don't use `document.write()`, you should only use that if you have in-body `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that javascript is attempting to assign the text to an element that hasn't been rendered yet. Try figuring out a way to put your innerHTML assignment towards the end of your body tag. You'll need to wrap it in another script tag.

Answer (score 0):

The code tries to run before the HTML has loaded. Try This:

```
window.onload = function () {
var name = "Person";
name = prompt("What's your name?");
document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML = "Welcome, " + name + "!";
}
```